# How can I add buttons over an absolute position iframe while still be able to interact with it?

Tags: html, css, iframe, css-position, z-index

My markup is exactly in this order:

```
  <iframeContainer>
    <iframe>
  </iframeContainer>
  <container>
    <button1>
    <button2>
    <sidebar>
    ...
 </container>
```

Where the `container` is supposed to be over the iframe itself. Unfortunately, I'm having issues getting them to play nice since my `container` has 100% w/h and that obviously doesn't allow clicks on the iframe itself. Example:

```js
const buttonThatIWannaClick = document.getElementById('buttonOverIframe');

buttonThatIWannaClick.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('I am able to click the button!');
});
```

```css
#videoContainer {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9998;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#buttonOverIframe {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

#videoContainer iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9998;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#openSidebar {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30px;
  color: white;
  transform: translate3d(0, 50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="videoContainer">

  <div id="buttonOverIframe">Button Inside Iframe</div>
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5qap5aO4i9A" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="openSidebar">Open Sidebar</div>
</div>
```

You can see that there's no way for me to interact with the iframe. **I understand that this is because the `container` has 100% width/height and even if it's not visible by the naked eye, the browser sees it as in front.

How can I re-arrange things such that:

1. I can interact with buttons over the iframe.
2. I can detect clicks outside the iframe/on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pointer-events: none;` to container and `pointer-events: initial` on active element

```js
const buttonThatIWannaClick = document.getElementById('buttonOverIframe');

buttonThatIWannaClick.addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('I am able to click the button!');
});
```

```css
#videoContainer {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9998;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#buttonOverIframe {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

#videoContainer iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9998;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#openSidebar {
  display: flex;
pointer-events: initial;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30px;
  color: white;
  transform: translate3d(0, 50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="videoContainer">

  <div id="buttonOverIframe">Button Over Iframe</div>
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5qap5aO4i9A" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="openSidebar">Open Sidebar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But how does this work? I feel as if this is a hack, not how things are supposed to be done.

Comment: Also, sorry, I edited the original snippet with **"Button Inside Iframe"**, maybe that gave the impression that the iframe's button needs to be over everything else. The iframe should be behind everything else but still interactable.

Comment: `pointer-events` defines if element reacts to events as `click` and so and allows you click through. So you will dissable it for container, bud allow it for buttons. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_pointer-events.asp

Comment: Aha, so am basically saying to the page "I don't care about the width/height of the container, you do whatever you want with that, but react to click events inside of it as if there was no container whatsoever".

Comment: yes. and by giving `pointer-events: initial` to buttons you are saying "but dont ignore theese guys", because otherwise they would inherit